# 16.04: editing /etc/sudoers to allow NetMan restart w/o password

Tags: networking, sudo, password

I want to be able to restart Network Manager without having to enter my password every time. I did `sudo visudo` and added this line:

`%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service`

No luck. It's still prompting me for my password when I try to restart NetMan. Is there a further step I've left out?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should be sufficient to achieve passwordless restart of network manager. However:

1. Do you run command exactly as you wrote it in sudoers file? For
   example you can not omit `.service` part unless your sudo rule looks
   like this:

   ```
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart network-manager*
   ```
2. Does `sudo --list` command output includes your command?
3. Try to put your rule on a last line of sudoers file.
4. Is target user in sudo group?

   ```
   groups $(whoami)
   ```

Comment: 1. I tried the command exactly as written, both prefixed by `/bin` and not, but it throws up a password dialog no matter how I write it. 2. Yes, it includes my command. 3. Yes, I only have one user on the system which is a member of the sudo group.